# Matching Popen.communicate() output with regular expressions doesn't work

Tags: python, regex, subprocess, stdout

I have code that roughly looks like this (the entire code is a bit too long to copy here):

```
import re
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

goodOutput = re.compile(r'\S+: 0x[0-9a-fA-F]{8} \d \d\s+->\s+0x[0-9a-fA-F]{8}')

p = Popen(['/tmp/myexe', param], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, cwd='/tmp')

stdout, stderr = p.communicate()

ret = goodOutput.match(stdout)
if ret == None:
   print "No match in: " + stdout
```

match() doesn't match this, but if I copy the stdout from the print statement and use that string in the above script as the value for stdout, it matches. So the regexp pattern should be all right. Also, if I read the string from stdin (stdout = sys.input.read()) it again works.

I've tried to rstrip() stdout as well, but that didn't help either (besides, shouldn't match() make this unnecessary?).

When I print stdout with repr() the string looks like

```
'xxx[a]: 0xff2eff00 4 7\t->\t0xff2eff00\n'
```

and if I try to match() to this it doesn't match. Is this an issue with the tab and newline characters and if so, what should I do?

Comment: @Makis: repr(stdout).strip() did not work ?

Comment: This isn't enough information.  Dump the value of stdout: `print repr(stdout)`, and eliminate the Popen call entirely: `stdout = output_of_repr`, to reproduce it in a self-contained way.  If that doesn't tell you what's happening, show us that code, so we can actually run it and see what's happening.

Comment: @Glenn Maynard: well, it clearly says "doesn't work"! I mean, what more could you ever need?

Comment: Glenn: As I said, I have tried matching the stdout and it matches if I set it manually rather than reading it from the pipe. So in effect I have done what you suggest already but maybe I wasn't clear enough in my question (the part "..but if I copy the stdout from the print statetement.." was my attempt at explaining this.

Comment: You havn't done what I said at all.  Again, *show us that code, so we can actually run it and see what's happening*.

Comment: pyfunc: nope, didn't help. Glenn: do you deliver company sensitive data to the net? What my script does is read a certain file WHICH I CAN NOT give to you, feeds it to an executable WHICH I CAN NOT give to you (that's the Popen() part, actually) and tries to read the output. Now, how would you use the entire (>100 line) script to verify what happens without those two files? I have tried to recreate the situation to a reasonable example which does the same. I HAVE dumped stdout and I HAVE removed the Popen() call and instead give exactly the stdout from the previous call instead to match().

Comment: And when I do it like that IT WORKS.

Comment: OK, now I think what the problem is. Sorry for getting agitated, but I really can't deliver the entire system. We all do not work in the Open Source World and I don't like the notion that in order to get help you have to deliver the entire SW. I spent a good deal of time recreating the problem in a simpler manner so it's rather annoying that this work is deemed worthless. I edit my question to include the new finding, any ideas now?

Comment: Why are you editing your question like this? You're putting code provided in answers into your question. Now we could just claim norepro and happily go home. WTF? voting to close

Comment: I have fixed the regexp string because I made some typos to it. And it still doesn't work but I'm starting to realise that since I can't provide the whole environment (some of which has a high security clearance) and because without it this looks impossible to solve I'm not going to get this to work any time soon.

Comment: My original thought was that maybe the output from the pipe is somehow different (special encoding etc) but I couldn't figure it out so I thought maybe someone else has tried something similar. It's simply not reasonable to assume that people can deliver full, working examples every time. Unless we turn SO into a place where only amateurs are allowed to ask questions.

Comment: sure, let's turn SO into a site where only clairvoyants are allowed to answer.

Comment: I think I'll take this to the meta discussion, but which would you do then: not ask any questions or post code that you are not allowed to? I spent a good moment to create a script that effectively does (or at least that was my goal) what my original script does without the need to for me to do illegal acts (posting code owned by my company).

Answer (score 1):

There still seem to be either typos in your regex or errors that lead to it not matching (extraneous `}`, too much whitespace).

Try

```
goodOutput = re.compile(r"\s*[^:]:s*0x[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\s+\d\s+\d\s+->\s+0x[0-9a-fA-F]{8}"`
```

and see if that helps.

Also, try `re.search()` vs. `re.match()` and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: I couldn't copy & paste, because the machine I'm doing this on is not in the net so I had to type that by hand. I fixed those typos, thanks for spotting them.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there is no leading space or such invisible characters in stdout ? If you copy paste what follow them but not these characters it would explain why your test 'by hand' works.

If so maybe you want to perform a `re.search` (match anywhere) instead of `re.match` (match at beginning) or remove these leading characters.

Comment: I checked the output with repr() and it doesn't show any leading spaces. I edited my question to show what repr() printed.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex has some random characters, with correct version of it everything matches:

```
>>> s = 'xxx[a]: 0xff2eff00 4 7\t->\t0xff2eff00\n'
>>> re.match(r'\S+: 0x[0-9a-f]{8} \d \d\s+->\s+0x[0-9a-f]{8}', s, re.I).group()
'xxx[a]: 0xff2eff00 4 7\t->\t0xff2eff00'
```